# Allocate a structure by calloc(): To which value the members are initialized?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

For example I have a `struct`

```
struct s{
    char c;
    int x;
};
```

And I use `calloc()` to allocate memory.

`s *sp = (s*) calloc(1, sizeof(s));`

**Now**, what will be the values of `sp->c` and `sp->x`?

Comment: `calloc()` initializes the memory to zeroes. `sp->c` and `sp->x` will be `0` (of type `char` and `int` respectively). BTW: casting the return value of `calloc()` is, at best, redundant (and may hide an error the compiler would warn you about if the cast wasn't there).

Comment: To answer the question in the title: chars are stored as numbers. Or did you mean the structure, not the char? The whole structure will be zeroed: all of its members, and any space left as padding.

Comment: If you do not want C++, add `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error bad compiler` / `#endif` at the top of your source file(s).

Answer (score 2):

> "*What will be the values of `sp->c` and `sp->x`?*"

Since `calloc()` sets all bits of the allocated memory to `0`, `c` and `x` will have the value of `0` if the `0` value representation of `int` and `char` is of all bits to `0` (which is common).

Note that in the case of pointers, the pointer might not be standard-compliant `NULL` pointer when just setting all bits to `0` as the C standard does not require the representation of `NULL` pointers to be all-zero-bits.

---

Side notes:

1.

```
struct s{
    char c;
    int x;
};

s *sp = (s*) calloc(1, sizeof(s));
```

can´t work as `s` isn´t a `typedef`d type; it is a structure tag. Therefore, You need to precede `s` by the `struct` keyword:

```
struct s *sp = (struct s*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct s));
```

2.

You do not need to cast the returned pointer from `calloc()` and other memory management functions and rather avoid it since it can add clutter to your code. -> [Do I cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

So, just do:

```
struct s *sp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct s));
```

Comment: What if instead of `struct` I have `class`? And on my compiler at least this does not work, I have to do the cast, it says it cannot initialize a variable of type [type]*  with a value of type void*

Comment: @platinoob_ First of all, classes belong to C++, not C. C and C++ are very different languages. C code doesn´t have to work with a C++ compiler and vice versa. This question was tagged with C and also the provided code is C code. I answered the question you had for C. If you have an issue in your specific C++ code, please ask a separate question and tag it with C++, not C. This doesn´t belong to here. It also requires much more information than to just show a little bit of information in this comment section. We need to see the exact code and exact compiler invocation command.

Comment: @ RobertS supports Monica Cellio, I am sorry if my comment was not clear, the "class instead of struct" thing was just a question, the comment was about me having to do the cast or else : `cannot initialize a variable of type 's *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'
        s *sp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct s));`

Comment: @platinoob_ The problem is: I can´t reproduce the problem. It is really better to make a separate question.